# Libvirt generated profiles

Tags: libvirt, profiles, apparmor

I'm using apparmor as hardening layer for libvirt-qemu , everything is OK , but there is one thing that I can't solve systematically, let me explain :

When create a new qemu instance , profile is generated from  /etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/TEMPLATE.qemu to a file with path /etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-81303229-df4c-4b18-b33b-277bcda81b0f for example .

When instance is shut-off profile is unloaded from kernel by apparmor and it is OK as expected. But if i remove the instance definitively, i would expect that profile is removed also from filesystem, but it is not and still present in filesystem. After some time I have very big mess in libvirt instance profile files

Yes .. I can write a cron job what will be delete unnecessary libvirt profile files ... but ..is there some more clear solution , maybe builtin function of apparmor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `libvirt undefine` to delete the stopped guest?  It appears that virt-aa-helper should delete an undefined domain but I think it is a bug and you should file a ticket.

You can use the virt-aa-helper command directly to remove the files which is probably the safest as it *should* deal with the dependencies for you.

An example command is:

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper -D -u libvirt-3c3d5aa2-f581-457d-b5ab-efbf9fdd4a6e
```

But it may be some edge case that they need to account for, where you can *undefine* a running instance to convert it to ephemeral. You would need to take care of that edge case.

*Note:* Because virt-aa-helper is intended to be run by libvirt you will have to use *sudo* with the command.  If you do not it will silently fail and not remove the profile.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, yes I'm using virsh undefine <virt-instance> and related profile still present on the disk ... Command you've adviced me with virt-aa-helper is working and profile is deleted as expected ..  If you think that libvirt should remove that profile after undefine instance .. I will report a bug ... Thanks for your help !